# WireFrame of Json formated geometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, wireframe

I would like to display the wireframe of a parallelepiped defined by vertexes in a Json  format using the following Three.js code

```
var testCube ={
                "metadata":{
                "version":json['version'],
                "type":json['type'],
                "uvs":json['n_uvs'],
                "normals":json['n_normals'],
                "faces":json['n_faces'],
                "generator":"io_three",
                "vertices":json['n_vertices'],
                                            },
                "faces":json['faces'],
                "vertices":json['vertices'],
                "normals":json['normals'],
                "uvs":[],
                "name":json['name']}

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

var model = loader.parse( testCube );

meshBox = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, model.materials[ 0 ] );

var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( meshBox.geometry );

var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 });

var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );

scene.add( wireframe );
```

however, the above code produce this kind of visualization:

[image: Image produce with Three.js]

while I would like to produce a visualization where also the internal wireframe is visible as the following:

[image: Image produce with Paraview]

**Question**: do you know how I can modify the above Three.js code to produce a full wireframe as displayed in the second picture?

**Upadate**: using the function `WireframeGeometry` you have the following plot:

[image]

Diagonals appear on each face of the mesh. Do yo know a function that does not produce diagonals?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Depends on what you want as the result. As an option, if you know size of a box and amount of segments, then you can build 6 grids of `THREE.LineSegments()` (one on each side of the box).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I would like to show also the internal wireframe. In other words if you remove the solid surface internal segments are visible. Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing `EdgesGeometry` with `WireframeGeometry`.

Comment: Hi WestLangley, thank you for your help. WireframeGeometry improves the plot as you can see in the edited post. However, in each cell there are diagonals that should not be there in order to obtain the result displayed in the second picture of the post. Is there another function that can be used to have the plot shown in the second figure? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, no. You will have to write that code yourself... Also, use @username, otherwise users may not be notified.

Comment: @Sim81 You can create 3 geometries for 3 sides and share them between pairs of `THREE.LineSegments()`, which will belong to opposite sides. As a base, you can use the source code of [`THREE.GridHelper()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/helpers/GridHelper.js) with some changes. But once again, it depends on what you want as result.

Comment: Hi @prisoner849 thank you for your answer. That seems a useful direction. If you can post it in the answer test box I can give you the bounty points. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is rough and imperfect, and it's a huge field for improvement and optimization.

You create one geometry and share it between two instances of `THREE.LineSegments()` for opposing sides of a box.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-15, 10, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .5));
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"gray"}));
scene.add(box);

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});
var params = box.geometry.parameters;
var geometryGridXY = Grid(params.width, params.height, params.widthSegments, params.heightSegments, "yellow");
var gridXYFront = new THREE.LineSegments(geometryGridXY, material);
gridXYFront.position.z = params.depth / 2 + 0.001;
box.add(gridXYFront);
var gridXYBack = new THREE.LineSegments(geometryGridXY, material);
gridXYBack.position.z = -params.depth / 2 - 0.001;
box.add(gridXYBack);

var geometryGridYZ = Grid(params.height, params.depth, params.heightSegments, params.depthSegments, "aqua");
var gridYZLeft = new THREE.LineSegments(geometryGridYZ, material);
gridYZLeft.position.x = -params.width / 2 - 0.001;
gridYZLeft.rotation.y = -Math.PI * .5;
box.add(gridYZLeft);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
  
  function Grid(width, height, widthSegments, heightSegments, color) {

    width = width || 1;
    height = height || 1;
    widthSegments = widthSegments || 1;
    heightSegments = heightSegments || 1;
    color = new THREE.Color(color !== undefined ? color : 0x444444);

    var stepWidth = width / widthSegments;
    var stepHeight = height / heightSegments;
    var halfWidth = width / 2;
    var halfHeight = height / 2;

    var vertices = [],
      colors = [], j = 0;

    for (let i = 0, k = -halfHeight; i <= heightSegments; i++, k += stepHeight) {

      vertices.push(-halfWidth, k, 0, halfWidth, k, 0);

      color.toArray(colors, j); j += 3;
      color.toArray(colors, j); j += 3;
    }

    for (let i = 0, k = -halfWidth; i <= widthSegments; i++, k += stepWidth) {

      vertices.push(k, halfHeight, 0, k, -halfHeight, 0);

      color.toArray(colors, j); j += 3;
      color.toArray(colors, j); j += 3;
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(vertices), 3));
    geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));

    return geometry;

  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you man, I will work on it. I think I gave you the bounty.